# Rails 3 save multiple (constant) values of a checkbox selection to Single DB Column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, serialization, constants

I have a constant called `PAYMENT_METHODS` in `venue.rb`.

```
PAYMENT_METHODS = {'Visa' => 1, 'MasterCard' => 2, 'American Express' => 3, 'Diners' => 4, 'JCB' => 5, 'Bankomat' => 6, 'sodexo' => 7, 'MA-Gutscheine' => 8 }
```

You can check/uncheck multipe payment types in a form (`payment_options` is a string):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "venue[payment_options][]", nil %>
<% Venue::PAYMENT_METHODS.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= f.check_box :payment_options, {:multiple => true}, value %>
  <%= label_tag key %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to save the values to the single Database Column `payment_options`, e.g. `[1,3,5]`. No matter what I check, it always saves `0`. What am I doing wrong? I am using `PostgreSQL`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You try to save a string to an int column?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options here.

#### String column

Serialize this to a string and save to a VARCHAR column. There are many ways.

Examples:

```
update orders set payment_options = '1,2,3'; -- comma separated list    
update orders set payment_options = '{"visa": 1, "amex": 1}'; -- json object
```

#### Integer column

Store your selections as bits in a single int column.

Example:

```
VISA = 0x01
MASTERCARD = 0x02
AMEX = 0x04
DINERS = 0x08

update order set payment_options = #{VISA | MASTERCARD}; -- int value 3
update order set payment_options = #{MASTERCARD | DINERS}; -- int value 10
```

Then later you can check the value like this

```
def visa?
  (payment_options & VISA) == VISA
end
```

Flags and bitwise operations can be a little hard for you, if you never used them. Comma-separated list is probably the easiest choice.

#### Array column

Apparently, [there are arrays in PostgreSQL](https://www.google.ru/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=postresql+array+column#hl=en&newwindow=1&sa=X&ei=9BdnT_fiLNTQ4QTtnvGHCA&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=postgresql+array+column&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=37d179d32fa6e967&biw=1340&bih=783), but I don't know much about this DB. Two previous options are universal and work in any database.

#### Many-to-many relationship

This had been covered zillion times. Keywords:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many
has_many :through
```

Comment: thx! One general question: Do you think this is the right way to store payment types? I also thought about a `PaymentType`model and a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many`relationship, but I think that is overkill...

Comment: Depends on how you are going to use it. As far as I understand your intentions, yes, it would be an overkill.